# Permutation without duplicates in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have N positions, and each position can be either 0 or 1. I have fixed number of 1s, and I want to permutate these fixed number of 1s in these N positions.

```
from itertools import permutations
p = [0 for k in xrange(6)]
for k in xrange(0,3):
        p[k] = 1
print(list(permutations(p)))
```

But above result contains four [0,0,0,1,1,1] in the list. I only want one of them. How can I get rid of these duplicates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could grab the positions of the 1s instead:

```
from itertools import combinations


def place_ones(size, count):
    for positions in combinations(range(size), count):
        p = [0] * size

        for i in positions:
            p[i] = 1

        yield p
```

In action:

```
>>> list(place_ones(6, 3))
[
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
]
```

Comment: Can this approach be used for 3+ kinds of values or is this only for 2 kinds of values?

Answer (score 7):

Set is perfect for this, as set does not not contain any duplicated element:

```
set(permutations(p))
```

Comment: It seems like set can not use index, then how can I grab each permutation out in the set?

Comment: `sorted([e for e in set(permutations(p))])` convert set into list, optionaly sort to impose an ordering

Comment: this is very inefficient, gets hung for high numbers, and high number of duplicates for higher numbers

Comment: @SayanDey agree, but what is the efficient solution?

Comment: Refer to @Ry s answer (first)

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

[`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/) provides the function [`multiset_permutations`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations):

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations

n_zeros, n_ones = 3, 3
for perm in multiset_permutations(n_zeros * (0,) + n_ones * (1,)):
    print(perm)
```

which outputs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```